# Capacitor: What is the _capuid in localStorage used for?

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

When running an Ionic app with Capacitor (v3) added as a web app, I can see that a key `_capuid` is being save to Window.localStorage. It's an UUID like c35b1ec0-20c4-4e89-ab07-145aa261edf5 for example.

[image]

What's the purpose of this `_capuid`? Looks like some kind of local installation ID ... Can we use it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It's stored by Capacitor's Device plugin and returned in `getInfo()` as `uuid` field.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/device#deviceinfo